# Codeigniter DB delete when timestamp is older than X minutes from current time

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to rewrite this query

`DELETE FROM users WHERE confirmed != 0 AND member_since < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);`

Into the CodeIgniter Active Record class syntax. The code I have right now isn't affecting any rows. I think it's, because I have the `(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)` inside `''` brackets.. But, when I don't use the brackets my controller falls apart.. Please take a look at the code below.

```
$this->db->where('confirmed !=', '0');
$this->db->where('member_since <', '(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)');
$this->db->delete('users');
```

If you have any idea how to rewrite the code to get it to work please let me know. Thank you for reading and hopefully for replies :)

BTW: the `member_since` column has a default value set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

PS: Should I just forget about the CI's syntax and write the query in a regular way(mySQL syntax)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass string as where condition.
So you just pass your condition as below.

```
$this->db->where("confirmed != 0 AND member_since < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)");
```

Comment: I am so stupid :D somehow I missed that in the documentation. Thank you. Will accept in 5 mins :D

Comment: It's okay. Download CI userguide and keep it in your machine. So you can easily refer anything on time.